# Adding 2D arrays fast in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to add two 2D arrays. I wonder if there is a faster way to do it than this:

```
    double** x=new double*[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {

            x[i]=new double[100];
    }
     //x y z are all the same dimension

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<100;j++) x[i][j]=y[i][j]/2.0+z[i][j]/2.0;
       }
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be good.

Comment: `double ** x=new double*[1000];` doesn't allocate a 2D array, it allocates a 1D array consisting of 1000 `double *` pointers.  Perhaps you intended `double x[1000][100];` instead?

Comment: [IPP](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/tc4600/intel/2017.0.098/ipp/common/ipp_manual/index.htm) might be able to do it faster, but I doubt you really want to add it as a dependency. It's mostly for signal processing., I believe.

Comment: `x[i][j]=y[i][j]/2.0+z[i][j]/2.0;` invokes *Undefined Behavior* as `x[i]` is an uninitialized pointer to nowhere. You would need `for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) { x[i] = new double[100]; for(int j=0;j<100;j++) ...`

Comment: Get your code correct first, worry about fast later.

Comment: What makes you think that you need to optimise for speed? Why do you need to make it faster? Before optimising speed, measure to determine how much faster you need to get. Also consider not optimising, premature optimising only gets you unreadable code while wasting development time. With nowadays compilers it is quite hard to even change their result with different code, even less speed it up.

Comment: An array of arrays can be horribly slow due to low spatial locality. If the data is rectangular, and it looks it here, consider using a single array of size M by N and do the indexing math yourself with `row * N + column`.

Answer (score 1):

For fast an easy operations on matrices, you may consider to use `std::valarray`. This (not so popular) container has been desigend for exactly that purpose.

I admit that they are not so easy to understand, especially not the slice or gslice part, but if you learned how to use them, then they are very powerful.

And on some machines, they have native support and are extremely fast.

Here is one (of many) possible examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <numeric>

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 10;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 20;
constexpr size_t MatrixSize = NumberOfRows * NumberOfColumns;

int main(void)
{
    // Define some valarrays
    std::valarray<double> y(MatrixSize);
    std::valarray<double> z(MatrixSize);

    // And fill them with some demo values
    std::iota(std::begin(y), std::end(y), 200);
    std::iota(std::begin(z), std::end(z), 400);

    // Perform mathematical operations on all elements of array
    y /= 2.0;
    z /= 2.0;
    // Simply add 2 arrays to a new one
    std::valarray<double> x =  y + z;

    // Display result
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MatrixSize; ++i) 
        std::cout << (((i % NumberOfColumns) == 0) ? "\n" : " " ) << x[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `valarray` is *designed* for efficiency, but few implementations actually optimize it at all ...

Comment: Yes, true. And only on some machines, they have native support and are extremely fast. And the future of ````std::valarray```` is also not so clear to me. Sad story . . .